# How to automatically place "read more" when characters hit X amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using a nice bit of open source code which pulls Google reviews.
Issue is, if a review is very long... it makes my site look weird. I need to set a max amount of characters, but give the user the option to read the full review. I'm not sure if this should be done through jQuery, CSS or what... Looking for some guidance.

See my issue here:
[image: Issue example]

My code is here:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
        placeId: 'place ID' //Find placeID @: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id
      , render: ['reviews']
      , min_rating: 5
      , max_rows:3
   });
});

/* https://github.com/peledies/google-places */
(function($) {

    $.googlePlaces = function(element, options) {

        var defaults = {
              placeId: 'place ID' // placeId provided by google api documentation
            , render: ['reviews']
            , min_rating: 0
            , max_rows: 0
            , rotateTime: false
        };

        var plugin = this;

        plugin.settings = {}

        var $element = $(element),
             element = element;

        plugin.init = function() {
          plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
          $element.html("<div id='map-plug'></div>"); // create a plug for google to load data into
          initialize_place(function(place){
            plugin.place_data = place;
            // render specified sections
            if(plugin.settings.render.indexOf('reviews') > -1){
              renderReviews(plugin.place_data.reviews);
              if(!!plugin.settings.rotateTime) {
                  initRotation();
              }
            }
          });
        }

        var initialize_place = function(c){
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-plug'));

          var request = {
            placeId: plugin.settings.placeId
          };

          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

          service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              c(place);
            }
          });
        }

        var sort_by_date = function(ray) {
          ray.sort(function(a, b){
            var keyA = new Date(a.time),
            keyB = new Date(b.time);
            // Compare the 2 dates
            if(keyA < keyB) return -1;
            if(keyA > keyB) return 1;
            return 0;
          });
          return ray;
        }

        var filter_minimum_rating = function(reviews){
          for (var i = reviews.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(reviews[i].rating < plugin.settings.min_rating){
              reviews.splice(i,1);
            }
          }
          return reviews;
        }

        var renderReviews = function(reviews){
          reviews = sort_by_date(reviews);
          reviews = filter_minimum_rating(reviews);
          var html = "";
          var row_count = (plugin.settings.max_rows > 0)? plugin.settings.max_rows - 1 : reviews.length - 1;
          // make sure the row_count is not greater than available records
          row_count = (row_count > reviews.length-1)? reviews.length -1 : row_count;
          for (var i = row_count; i >= 0; i--) {
            var stars = renderStars(reviews[i].rating);
            var date = convertTime(reviews[i].time);
            html = html+"<div class='review-item'><div class='review-meta'><span class='review-author'>"+reviews[i].author_name+"</span><span class='review-sep'>, </span><span class='review-date'>"+date+"</span></div>"+stars+"<p class='review-text'>"+reviews[i].text+"</p></div>"
          };
          $element.append(html);
        }
        
        var initRotation = function() {
            var $reviewEls = $element.children('.review-item');
            var currentIdx = $reviewEls.length > 0 ? 0 : false;
            $reviewEls.hide();
            if(currentIdx !== false) {
                $($reviewEls[currentIdx]).show();
                setInterval(function(){ 
                    if(++currentIdx >= $reviewEls.length) {
                        currentIdx = 0;
                    }
                    $reviewEls.hide();
                    $($reviewEls[currentIdx]).fadeIn('slow');
                }, plugin.settings.rotateTime);
            }
        }

        var renderStars = function(rating){
          var stars = "<div class='review-stars'><ul>";
                            
          // fill in gold stars
          for (var i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
            stars = stars+"<li><i class='star'></i></li>";
          };

          // fill in empty stars
          if(rating < 5){
            for (var i = 0; i < (5 - rating); i++) {
              stars = stars+"<li><i class='star inactive'></i></li>";
            };
          }
          stars = stars+"</ul></div>";
          return stars;
        }

        var convertTime = function(UNIX_timestamp){
          var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
          var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
          var time = months[a.getMonth()] + ' ' + a.getDate() + ', ' + a.getFullYear();
          return time;
        }

        plugin.init();

    }

    $.fn.googlePlaces = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('googlePlaces')) {
                var plugin = new $.googlePlaces(this, options);
                $(this).data('googlePlaces', plugin);
            }
        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
#map-plug {display:none;}

#google-reviews {
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
//display: grid;
//grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
}

.review-item {
margin:0 auto;
padding:1em;
flex: 1 1 20%;
}

@media ( max-width:1200px) {
  .review-item { flex: 1 1 40%; }
}

@media ( max-width:450px) {
  .review-item { flex: 1 1 90%; }
}

.review-meta, .review-stars {text-align:center; font-size:115%;}
.review-author { text-transform: capitalize; font-weight:bold; }
.review-date {opacity:.6; display:block;}
.review-text {  line-height:1.55; text-align:left; max-width:32em; margin:auto;}

 

.review-stars ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin:0; padding:0;
}

.review-stars ul li {
float: left;
margin-right: 1px;
line-height:1;
}

.review-stars ul li i {
  color: #E4B248;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-style:normal;
}
.review-stars ul li i.inactive { color: #c6c6c6;}
.star:after { content: "\2605"; }
```

```html
<div id="google-reviews"></div>
```

Comment: Something like: `"123456789".substr(0, 6) + " read more..."`? It will output `// 123456 read more...`. 6 being the maximum amount of characters in a string.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How would I put your example into this? As when I try to include it, it breaks the page. `html = html+"<div class='review-item'><div class='review-meta'><span class='review-author'>"+reviews[i].author_name+"</span><span class='review-sep'>, </span><span class='review-date'>"+date+"</span></div>"+stars+"<p class='review-text'>"+reviews[i].text+"</p></div>"`

Comment: Try `reviews[i].text.substr(0, 100) + " read more..."`

Comment: With : `"<p class='review-text'>"reviews[i].text.substr(0, 100) + "read more..."</p></div>"` It's causing errors for some reason. Can you think of the reason why? /or if there's an alternative way?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: " Unexpected identifier 'reviews' "

Comment: `"<p class='review-text'>" + reviews[i].text.substr(0, 100) + "read more..." + "</p></div>"` should fix it

Comment: Awesome. Fixed! Thank you very, very much.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll post it as answer for you to mark as solved.

Comment: Yep! No problem, could you also include how to do it based on how many words opposed to characters too?

Comment: Google Maps API? Really? I am removing your tag.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, the code has Google Maps api within it. Chill out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method will return the part of a string between the start index and a number of characters after it and will truncate your text.

Ex:

```
reviews[i].text.substr(0, 100 /* amount of characters */) + " read more..."
```